# ng-repeat in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<td >
    <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="K in datavalue">
        <div ng-if="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)">    
            {{K.amount}}
        </div>
    </div>  

    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value"  class="form-control" name="cvalue"   ng-model="T.cvalue"  required/> 
</td>
```

Here I do a loop where an expression is also checked.
If it is true then show the value, else show the input box. But my issue is if I insert the input box inside loop, then the input box will display the number if the expression fails.
Otherwise it will show the value of `{{K.amount}}` if the expression is `true` and the text box together.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`ng-if` creates an isolated scope. Try using `ng-show` instead, so the `ng-model` on your input element will bind to the right scope:

```
<div ng-if="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)">
    {{K.amount}}
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value" class="form-control" name="cvalue" ng-model="T.cvalue" required/> 
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-if` also removes the element from the DOM and recreates it. `ng-show` simply hides it leaving it in the DOM.

Answer (score -1):

use ng-show and ng-hide

```
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="K in datavalue">
    <div ng-show="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)">
       {{K.amount}}
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)">
       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter value"  class="form-control" name="cvalue"   ng-model="T.cvalue"  required/> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but it is repeating the input box as number of times the expression fails

Comment: so i didn't understand well what do you ask. Do you want the input box to be insert only once?

Comment: so put it out of the div with ng-repeat to have if only once.

Comment: <input type="text" placeholder="Enter valueg"  class="form-control" name="cvalue" id="{{T.id}}"  ng-model="T.cvalue"  required/>

Comment: i hv initiated a function to hide the input but, it is not hiding.

Comment: <div class="form-group" ng-repeat="K in datavalue">
    <div ng-show="(p.id == K.emp_id && T.id == K.component_id)" ng-init="hideinputbox(T.id)">
       {{K.amount}}
    </div>

Comment: $scope.hideinputbox = function (k) { 
  
   $("input#k").hide();
  }